# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'LoginComponent' before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following module:

```
export interface IAuthenticatorService {
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean>;
  logout(): Observable<boolean>;
  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean>;
}

export interface IConfig {
  authenticatorService: Type<IAuthenticatorService>;
}

export const AUTHENTICATOR_SERVICE_TOKEN =
  new InjectionToken<IAuthenticatorService>('AUTHENTICATOR_SERVICE_TOKEN');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
})
export class AuthenticatorModule {
  static forRoot(config?: IConfig): ModuleWithProviders<AuthenticatorModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthenticatorModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AUTHENTICATOR_SERVICE_TOKEN,
          useClass:
            (config && config.authenticatorService) ||
            DefaultAuthenticatorService,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Inside of LoginComponent, I am injecting the authentication service in the following manner:

```
  constructor(
    @Inject(AUTHENTICATOR_SERVICE_TOKEN)
    private authenticationService: IAuthenticatorService
  ) {}
```

I am getting the error:

authenticator.module.ts:30 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'LoginComponent' before initialization

I know this is probably due some circular dependency. However, I am not sure how I can avoid it. My idea is to create a module where the module user can pass a different implementation of the authentication service.

Comment: Move `AUTHENTICATOR_SERVICE_TOKEN` and `IAuthenticatorService` to separate file

Comment: It worked after I moved to separate file as suggested by @yurzui

Comment: @yurzui Please explain the mechanism！